# Fonts and background image with tailwind, not detected in export next js export

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

Hello I'm using tailwind css in my Next project and set local fonts, background image for pages, but when I export project and generated HTML and css files, HTML can't find fonts and background image. After reviewing generated css file I noticed it's url was incomplete and doesn't start with ./ signs. The generated addresses is as follows:
_next/static/media/iransans.1a37d2b9.ttf
_next/static/media/bg.aa581a5c.png

Comment: Can You add link to the repo ? Or provide your code ?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].